# Lumen uses .env file from laravel when using curl

Tags: laravel, curl, laravel-5, environment-variables, lumen

I have an application with laravel and one with lumen, both have different databases.

When I make a post call via postman to lumen, it is unsing his own database.

But when I do a curl call from laravel with `ixudra/curl` lumen tries to use the database name that is written in the `laravel/.env` file from the laravel project and not the `lumen/.env`. Is it because both the config is cached globally with php so lumen think it has already loaded it and is using the one from laravel instead?

Lumen has no `config` folder I can't hardcode the value there.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a config folder in your lumen app, and copy the database.php file from `vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/database.php`, this way you can make necessary changes to your database configuration, if required.

Comment: But how does lumen know that it has to use the new database file?

Comment: Lumen's Application class which is bootstrapped via bootstrap/app.php, looks for all the configuration files under <project root>/config folder first. If the config file doesn't exist there, then it will look for any config folders within the vendor directory. So if you do not have config/database.php, Lumen will by default pull the vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/database.php

Comment: okay, but why does lumen uses another .env file when laravel is making a request call to the lumen server?